# Is it allowed to use full qualified classnames for parameters of nested classes?

Tags: c++, coding-style, standards

Is this valid C++ code? It contains the fully qualified classname **inside the declaration**. I'm referring to the parameter `const A::B & param` within the class definition.

I can compile it with g++. I've never seen it before, so I'd like to know, if the standard actually allows it.

```
namespace Foo
{  
  class  A 
  {
    class  B 
    {
    public: 
      void foo( const A::B & param);
    }; 
  }; 


  void A::B::foo (const A::B & param)
  {
  }
}
```

I checked the https://isocpp.org/search/google?q=argument+lists without much success.

Comment: Yes, it is allowed.  Why wouldn't it be?

Comment: are you refering to `const A::B & param` ?

Comment: Just to be clear: What do you mean with "parameters of nested classes"? Do you mean the function arguments?

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818: Yes, I'm refering to `const A::B & param`. @NathanOliver: "Why would it not be allowed?" Because `void A::B::foo( const ... );` would not be allowed inside the method. @MaxLanghof: Yes, I mean the method arguments.